# How to fix this Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I click the facebook like button on one of my posts on my blog, it registers a "like" on every post on my blog. I am trying to get it so that if I click "like" on a post, it only works for that post in particular.

Do you see what I've done wrong?  Thanks for your help, if you can

This is my html tag

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

this is in my header. Note, it says "example.com" here, that's just because I didn't want to post my actual domain name. On my site, I use my real domain name there

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My example website"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my example website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/2011/pic-of-your-mama/"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my facebook id"/>
```

This is going just after my body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'myfacebookid',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

And this is what I have for the actual button

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myappid&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://example.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button there is:

> `<fb:like href="http://example.com"`

I think you forgot to set a proper URL there (probably the URL of the blogpost you like).

Comment: no, that's where I put my domain name for my blog....I just didn't want to write my real domain name here.  Am I not supposed to write my domain name there?

Comment: dont have to, if you dont it uses the current page url

Comment: You are supposed to write something like `http://michaelsblog.com/post1234.html` there.

Comment: @Cobra_Fest, I put a post url, then I have to create separate scripts for every post....Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Smart blog systems allow you to use the post URL in their templates, which is what you could do.

Comment: @Treemonkey are you saying that if I don't put a URL, then it will independently for each post?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what blog platform you use, but if you're using Blogger, you can put this attribute `expr:href='data:post.url'`in your fb:like tag. The expr prefix will analyse the value in the quote against the blog data.

So naturally your Facebook like tag would be like `<fb:like expr:href='data:post.url' send='true' show_faces='true' width='450'/>`